# ¿Cómo capturar el sub dominio en una vista de django?

Tags: django, views

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en `django` con muchos subdominios. Por ejemplo www.mysite.com, mx.mysite.com, es.mysite.com, nz.mysite.com, todas estas direcciones tienen que redireccionar a la misma aplicación de `django` y hacer que la página html con el idioma del país.

¿hay alguna manera de capturar el subdominio en el views.py?

Necesito algo como esto en views.py:

```
######## VIEWS.PY ###########
def hompage(request):
    subdomain = #HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO CAPTURE THE SUBDOMAIN 
    if subdomain=='www':
        contextdict = {"Language": "English"}
    else if subdomain=='mx':
        contextdict = {"Language": "Spanish"}
    return render(request, 'mysite/index.html', contextdict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a internacionalizar toda la app, tenerlo en una vista no será lo más optimo, ya que vas a tener que implementar eso mismo en todas las vistas, por lo que te recomiendo el uso de Middlewares que se encarguen de eso, o en su defecto, usar procesadores de contexto. Te daré el ejemplo de un Middleware:

```
class SubDomainLanguage(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            subdomain = request.META['HTTP_HOST'].split('.')[0]
            if subdomain == 'www':
                subdomain = 'en'
            request.session['django_language'] = subdomain
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Luego en settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'subdomainmiddleware.SubDomainLanguage',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    ...
)
```

Para recuperar los valores de eso desde una vista, lo tendrás disponible en `request.LANGUAGE_CODE`, aquí te puedes aprovechar de los procesadores de contexto para darle uso en tus templates.

```
def site_language_context_processor(request):
    return {
        'Language': request.LANGUAGE_CODE
    }
```

En settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'context_processors.site_language_context_processor',
                ...
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Espero haberte ayudado, cualquier duda comenta